# Merge branched code not in the repository

Tags: git, version-control

A small team had a project not under any revision control.  I came on board and put it under git.  I got all of the team into the habit of git except for one developer who continued to develop from his code base that had no revision control.  So, this developer has what is essentially a branch of the repository without any revision control.  We need to get his changes back into the git repo so we're all on the same page.  How would I go about merging his code that has no connection to git?

What about this: I create a git branch on my repo.  I replace all of my files with his files.  Make a commit to the branch and then do a branch merge back onto the master branch.

The drawback to this is that I will have to manually remove any files that were removed from that git repo that still exist in his code base.  Manually resolving conflicts is a given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you described is sound. If you start the branch (onto which you commit his changes) from the (approximate) commit where he took off, Git will be able to do a three-way merge (albeit with a very old base). Specifically, Git will do the right thing for files deleted in the mainline that he's kept around. Overall it probably won't be fun but it's about as good as it'll get.

Comment: Thanks.  Rolling back the git to the location he split off from is a nice improvement to the procedure.